# Recurring (daily) messages to a specific channel by my Slack App

Tags: scheduled-tasks, slack-api

I'm writing a slack app which provides some stats about a service by demand using [slash commands](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands).

The command calls my web api, I calculate stuff and return a formatted JSON that slack parses as a message.

I would like to do the same but automatically, every day, at midnight.

What I could do is set up the scheduling in my own server and call a webhook, which would be fine except that I want my service to be simple, passive, stateless and just respond to requests.

Is there a way to set up recurring messages in a way that slack calls my API periodically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Slack does currently not provide a "scheduling" function in its API for calling an external service.

So you need to either use a local scheduling service (e.g. cron) on your server or an external web-based scheduling service. I personally use for my apps a free service called [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/), which provides exactly the kind of functionality that you are requesting.

Comment: This is a very good service, thanks for bringing it to my attention